# Problem 14 chapter 7 from PMA Rudin

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

Rudin write that $f$ is continuous function on $\mathbb{R}^1$ but he does not define $f$ on segment $(\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3})$?

What is the matter with this moment?

Comment: I guess he takes any continuous function between $1/3$ and $2/3$ such that $f(1/3)=0$ and $f(2/3)=1$. For example, $f(x)=3(x-2/3)+1$ for $x\in(1/3 , 2/3)$ but it is one among an infinity of examples.

Comment: @MoebiusCorzer, It sounds pretty good!

Comment: @MoebiusCorzer. Else once question. In interval $[1,2]$ we define $f$ such that $f(1)=1$ and $f(2)=0$ which is continuous. For example, $f(x)=-x+2$. Right?

Comment: Yes, it is right. Of course, to remain general, you can't assume that $f$ is exactly this function, but it is an intuitive example of such a function.

Comment: @MoebiusCorzer, Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rudin provides you with certain properties of the function $f$. He does not specify what the function is, and he doesn't need to: the question is not about a specific function, it's about any function which satisfies all of these properties.

Comment: I think that you did not answer to my question! He write that $f$ is continuous on real line but he does not define $f$ on $(1/3,2/3)$. Maybe i don't understand you :( Can you expalin it please?

Comment: @RFZ I have an odd number $n$. Is $n^2$ odd or even? Can you answer without me defining $n$?

Comment: @DavidSchneider-Joseph, it's definitely odd! You second question confused me little bit!

Comment: Rudin has told you something about the function but hasn't told you precisely what function it is, just as I told you that $n$ is odd but I didn't tell you what number precisely it is. Yet you were able to answer a question about $n$, so why can't you answer a question about $f$?

Comment: Sorry! Just now I understood it. Maybe I can't understand it since sometimes i have problems with English language :(